# error connection when trying to connect the oracle database

Tags: oracle

An error was encountered performing the requested operation:

Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12528, TNS:listener: all appropriate instances are blocking new connections

Vendor code 12528

any help ? -thanks in advance

Comment: Ever heard of Google? You should try it some time.

Comment: yes i try it many times but i cant find the right solution, im using vmware workstation 9.0.

i think the error is typically displayed when the database is in NOMOUNT or RESTRICTED state?.
how can i possibly check the services of the listener to see if the service is in BLOCKED state?